# Getting a PeerServer key

Tags: javascript, p2p, peerjs

[The PeerJS Documentation](https://peerjs.com/docs.html#api) says

> The 'key' we're passing in to the Peer constructor is a PeerServer cloud API key. You can use ours for now, but you should [sign up for your own free key](https://peerjs.com/peerserver.html).

However, the given link just leads to [this](https://peerjs.com/peerserver.html) page, which doesn't have instructions on how to get a PeerServer key.

So, **How do I get a PeerServer Key?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PeerJS documentation is old. You do not need a PeerServer key anymore (This change is permanent). Just omit the key option -

```
const peer = new Peer()
```

Answer (score 1):

This would have saved me three hours if the documentation was more clear. I thought I'd add that you can include an ID for your client and still use the cloud server.
`let peer = new Peer('clientID')`. You only have to exclude the second argument (options) from Peer().